# Is there a way to print out the first and the last character of each line next to each other?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file from which I'd like to print out the lines' first and last character directly next to each other.

For example:

```
The value of x is 5
The value of y is 8
The value of z is 2
```

And the output would be:

```
T5
T8
T2
```

I've figured out the command for printing out the first and the last character separately, but I don't know how to concatenate them in a way that would give me the wanted result.

first: `cut -c1`
last: `grep -o '.$'`

Comment: And for a line containing only one character such as `x`, do you want `x`, `xx` or nothing? How about for empty lines?

Comment: Beware that with the GNU implementation of `cut`, `cut -c1` gives you the first byte (same as `cut -b1`), not first character. `grep -o '^.'` gives you the first character (for lines with at least one character).

Comment: I haven't really thought of that since every line in the file is longer than a single character. My problem is that the lengths' of the lines vary, so I cannot use ``cut -c1,14`` to print out the first and the fourteenth (last) character for example.

Comment: Is there maybe a regular expression for last characters that I can use in the cut (or any other) command to achieve this?

Comment: @squirrelfeeder please don't ask `is there a way to?` questions ... the answer is always a `yes` ... a `how to ?` question actually asks for a solution

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n 's/\(.\).*\(.\)/\1\2/p'
```

Or:

```
pcregrep -o1 -o2 '(.).*(.)'
```

Would give you that for text lines containing at least 2 characters.

Comment: In the `sed` command, is there a reason to use `-n` and `p` instead of using just `sed 's/\(.\).*\(.\)/\1\2/'`?